# <asp:combobox> the dropdown box is positioned way to the right?! I want it to position directly below the textbox

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I hope somebody can help me with this problem because it's driving me nuts!

I have a C#, asp.net web page (with Master.Page) and in that web page I've placed a  and inside that  I've placed a combo box (from the AJAX Toolkit). With multiple items attached to the combobox and the user clicks the down arrow, a dropdown box appears (usually) right below the comboboxes textbox. In my case this dropdown box appears way out to the right! I mean it's out of the viewable page! Is there a reason for this? What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample of my code:
    
       
           
           Mild
           Medium
           Hot

Thanks in advance for your help
Steve

Comment: what is **mild medium hot**?Not clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with question. Perhaps you mean your values of dropdown doesn't come below the textbox. If this is the case, you have to fix the CSS by adjusting it as per your requirement.